# amdgpu kernel module not loading in ubuntu 21.10 ryzen 7 5700g

Tags: amdgpu

I am a new linux user, currently running ubuntu 21.10 on ryzen 7 5700g apu. Every time I boot my system, I have to edit from grub and add nomodeset, I guess the gpu driver is failing to load properly..how to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you provide the `xrandr --listproviders` output in your question?

Comment: Thanks for asking but somehow the issue got fixed on its own, now everything is working just as it should….thank you again

Comment: nice to read them =) !